# HiBench Benchmar suite error: INPUT_HDFS: unbound variable

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I want to execute Kmeans algorithm with HiBench, but when I execute the script prepare.sh, I have the following error:

```
patching args=
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/conf/00-default-properties.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/conf/01-default-streamingbench.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/conf/10-data-scale-profile.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/conf/20-samza-common.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/conf/30-samza-workloads.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/workloads/kmeans/conf/00-kmeans-default.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hduser/HiBench/workloads/kmeans/conf/10-kmeans-userdefine.conf
Probing spark verison, may last long at first time...
probe sleep jar: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.2-tests.jar
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hduser/HiBench/bin/functions/load-config.py", line 556, in <module>
load_config(conf_root, workload_root, workload_folder, patching_config)
File "/home/hduser/HiBench/bin/functions/load-config.py", line 165, in load_config
check_config()
File "/home/hduser/HiBench/bin/functions/load-config.py", line 172, in check_config
assert HibenchConf.get(prop_name, None) is not None, "Mandatory configure missing: %s" % prop_name
AssertionError: Mandatory configure missing: hibench.hdfs.master
/home/hduser/HiBench/bin/functions/workload-functions.sh: line 39: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
start HadoopPrepareKmeans bench ./prepare.sh: line 25: INPUT_HDFS: unbound variable
```

I have set the configurations on the file `99-user_defined_properties.conf.template`. The configurations are :

```
# Hadoop home
hibench.hadoop.home     /usr/local/hadoop/bin

# Spark home
hibench.spark.home      /PATH/TO/YOUR/SPARK/ROOT

# HDFS master, set according to hdfs-site.xml
hibench.hdfs.master     hdfs://localhost:54310

# Spark master
#   standalone mode: `spark://xxx:7077`
#   YARN mode: `yarn-client`
#   unset: fallback to `local[1]`
hibench.spark.master        yarn-client
```

How can I solver this?

Answer (score 0):

`AssertionError: Mandatory configure missing: hibench.hdfs.master`

You need to fix this configuration error.

Did you name your file properly? `99-user_defined_properties.conf.template` is the *template*, the actual configuration file is supposedly named `99-user_defined_properties.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

`hibench.hdfs.master` sets IP address of the HDFS master node. The default value is http://127.0.0.1:8020. But if your cluster has a different address, you have to update it in `hadoop.conf`. Usually, you can find the right IP address in Hadoop's configuration file `core-site.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same error. I could solve it by manually setting hibench.master.hostname and hibench.slaves.hostname in hibench.conf file. Ensure that the hdfs port in hadoop.conf file is specified correctly as specified in hadoop configuration files.